# How to include collections in a users document in Firebase / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am new to coding and swift and I'm trying out lots of different things and working with firebase. In my app I'm getting step data using HealthKit and using that to practise with data in swift.

I have made the app get the users steps and convert them into points. 1,000 steps = 2 points. In the App there is a selection of "boxes" to choose from. The aim is to fill these "boxes" up with points. However you can only work towards filling up two "boxes" at a time (haven't made code that limits user to supporting 2 boxes at a time yet).

I have written code so that when you tap a "box" takes you to a detailed view of the "box" with a button labelled "WorkTowards". When this button is tapped, it gets added to "workingTowardsBoxes" which is displayed in the user's profile to indicate which boxes are being worked on.

I want to make the "boxes" a user is working towards be stored with their other data like username, bio etc. in their document on firebase but am unsure how to do this.

I'm new to firebase too but I imagine there is a way to give a field two separate values and the values being a document in a different collection.

The "Boxes" are stored in a collection in firebase so each "Box" has it's own uid. I need a field in the users document that contains two "Boxes" titled "activelyWorkingTowardsBoxes". The values in this field should change when the user changes the "Box" they are working on.

At this stage I want to have the "boxes" a user wants to 'workTowards' to be stored in the user's firebase document. Then I will work on adding the points to the boxes.

The code for the UserModel:

```
struct UserModel {
    var username : String
    var pic : String
    var bio: String
    var uid : String
    
    // something like this needs to be included?:
   // var activelyWorkingOnBoxes: WorkingOnBoxes
}
```

The code for the Boxes model is:

```
struct Box: Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    var box_name: String
    var box_type: String
    var box_profileImage: String
  
    // To identify whether it is being supported...
    var isWorkingOn: Bool = false
    
}
```

The Code For The WorkingOnBoxes is:

```
struct WorkingOnBoxes: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var box: Box

}
```

Here are my 'Working on' functions:

```
 func isWorkingOn() -> Bool {
        
        return sharedData.workingOnBoxes.contains { boxData in
            return self.boxData.id == boxData.id
        }
    }

    func addToWorkingOn() {
        
        if let index = sharedData.workingOnBoxes.firstIndex(where: {
            
            boxData in
            return self.boxData.id == boxData.id
        }){
            // Remove from working on...
            sharedData.workingOnBoxes.remove(at: index)
        }
        else {
            // Add to working on...
            sharedData.workingOnBoxes.append(boxData)
        }
    }
```

Any Help Would Be Much Appreciated!

Comment: Look into Firebase with Custom objects/Codable. It will simplify your work.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. The code shows you want something like this `var activelyWorkingOnBoxes: WorkingOnBoxes` and then when looking at the `WorkingOnBoxes` model, it has one property: `Box`, so it's not clear why the property is `Boxes` - plural but then only stores one Box. Then a `Box` has strings. There doesn't appear to be any other relationship to that data so why not just store it in the UserModel? e.g. `UserModel` would also have properties of `box_name` etc? Or is the intent to store a series of boxes in the `Users` object? Can you clarify what you're attempting to do?

Comment: Sorry for the late response and the messy question! Essentially there are a list of boxes (like there would be a list of products on an e-commerce app). When the user clicks the button to 'work on' the box (like add to basket on e-commerce), that box should be added as part of the users profile on firebase (e.g. items in basket saved on firebase in an e-commerce app). When the "Work On" button is tapped, that box id should be added as a box the user is working on in their firebase document.